# sendpfast scapy to send spoofed udp

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

Using the `sendpfast` function, how can I send UDP Packets from a randomized source? I need to do this for network simulation experimentation purposes.

I have a code like this where I set source IP and port:

```
IP1 = Ether() / IP(src=self.IPsrc,dst=self.IPdst)
UDP1 = UDP(sport=self.IPsrcport, dport=self.IPdstport);
pkt = IP1 / UDP1
sendpfast(pkt/"Hello World", mbps=5, loop=1000)
```

I would like to randomize it for every packet.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `RandIP` function for ip:

```
from scapy.all import RandIP
IP1 = Ether() / IP(src=RandIP(), dst=self.IPdst)
```

and for the port create your own:

```
import random
sport = random.randint(1024,65535)
UDP1 = UDP(sport=sport, dport=self.IPdstport);
```